# Gradle is failing to build with JCenter (using Unity + Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle, jcenter

So I updated Firebase to the latest version (in my Unity game), as my previous version of Firebase had an error with working on iOS devices. And now I can't build with gradle for android devices.

Unity version: 2018.2.0f2
Firebase version: 5.4.3

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Firebase'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Firebase:classpath'.
   > Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.0.1/manifest-merger-26.0.1.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.0.1/ddmlib-26.0.1.jar
   > Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.0.1/dvlib-26.0.1.jar
   > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/26.0.1/common-26.0.1.jar
```

So, it seems that JCenter is missing some files needed by the latest version of firebase. I've read that putting **google()** above **jcenter()** in the apps .gradle file should force it to look at googles maven repo first, but it doesn't seem to help.

My projects gradle file looks like the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing a bunch of things, but nothing resolves this issue.
Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `allprojects` has no repositories.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added **google()** and **jcenter()** to my **allprojects** repositories. It doesn't change any of the errors. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I met with the same after adding firebase. Is there any fix for the issue?

Comment: @IndikaWijesooriya No solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

So, i had exactly the same problem and tried out a lot.
What worked for me is to clear the .gradle folder inside my %Userfolder%
When you build it will download the entire folder again (Unity will say it crashed, but Java is going strong). and after that I could build again!

Hopes this works!

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip! I ended up upgrading Unity and Firebase lol. Which was a pain, but the result ended up working.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was facing the same issue what worked for me is

1.Change the position of jcenter and google in project gradle file and in also all the other module you have in your project. Like in mine I have crashlytics, fabric so just remember to make the changes in their build.gradle file as well

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
 }
```

to

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
 }
```

2. Before building your project again go to your project folder and delete the .gradle folder from your project and then build your project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I saw that your approach has worked for a lot of people. But I tried it and it still had issues. I ended with upgrading Unity and Firebase, which resolved my issues.